# Javascript: Passing a function as argument which will be executed at onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to creat a confirm box based on the idea that when the button is clicked, a div is appended
to the body, and its OK button executes a function given as argument. I managed to do it if the function name is not a variable, but in this case I would need as many confirm boxes as many types of functions I have.

Here's the html button:

`<button onclick=" executeAfterConfirmed( myFunc );">SHOW</button>`

Here's the confirm box function:

```
function execAfterConfirmed( functionToExecute , arg ){
    $("body").prepend("<div id='createdConfirmDiv' ><img id='closeImg' src='close.png' height=30 onclick='$(\"div#createdConfirmDiv\").remove()'>CONFIRM ?<br><button class='myConfirmButton'   id='yesButton' onclick='$(\"div#createdConfirmDiv\").remove();" + functionToExecute + "("+arg+")'>YES</button><button class='myConfirmButton' onclick='$(\"div#createdConfirmDiv\").remove()'>NO</button></div>");
```

}

However, I got Unexpected token (

Comment: I typed the function declaration wrong, its name is executeAfterConfirmed. The problem is still relevant.

Comment: `executeAfterConfirmed( 'myFunc' );` ??? FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: How is your "myFunc" defined?

Comment: function myFunc(myNr){
 if(myNr)
 $.post(
  "test.php",
  {
   nr:myNr
  },
  function(request){
   $("input").next().next().remove();
   $("input").next().after("<span>"+request+"</span>");   
  }
 ); 
 else
 showMyAlert("Nothing in input");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the handler programmatically...

```js
function myFunc() {
  alert("myFunc!");
}

function executeAfterConfirmed(functionToExecute, arg) {  
  var $show = $("#show-button").hide();  
  
  $("body").prepend("<div id='createdConfirmDiv'>Test dialog<br><button>OK</button></div>");
  
  $("#createdConfirmDiv button").one("click", function(e){
    functionToExecute(arg);
    $("#createdConfirmDiv").remove();
    $show.show();
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-button" onclick="executeAfterConfirmed(myFunc);">SHOW</button>
```

Comment: @Catgocat because the question was tagged jQuery and the OP's code uses jQuery.

Comment: It looks like the function is executing multiple times for a single button click, after clicking 'SHOW' several times and then clicking 'OK'.

Comment: @AlexW this is a stripped down example to demonstrate how to bind the handler programmatically. His actual code is (presumably) going to remove the generated div.

Comment: thank you very much, I tried it, works perfectly,  as I wanted.

Comment: yes, clicking on YES or NO will remove the confirm box

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did understand your problem, as you are trying to describe. Here is a solution:

```
function confirmBox(button, message, func) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
       var re = confirm(message);

       if (re) func();
    })    
}

confirmBox( document.getElementById('button'),
            "You clicked because you liked me.",
            function(){
                // do stuff
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect. But I'd like to use my own confirm box, not javascript's official one.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.createdConfirmDiv{display(none;}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id='createdConfirmDiv' >
<img id='closeImg' src='close.png'width="www" height="30" onclick="(remove(0)">CONFIRM?
<br>
<button class='myConfirmButton'   id='yesButton' onclick=("remove(1)");>YES
</button>
<button class='myConfirmButton' onclick=("remove(2)";)>NO
</button>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
myFunc function(f,a){
document.getElementById('createdConfirmDiv').sytle.display='block');



}


remove function(r){
document.getElementById('createdConfirmDiv').sytle.display='none');
if (r==0){

}
if (r==1){

}
```